# Get the current category slug in Wordpress / Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

In my `Single.php` I'm trying to get the current posts category slug:

```
$category = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
$cat_slug = $category->slug;
```

But it doesn't return anything. And there's definitely a category on the post. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `get_the_category()` and then do a `print_r()` to see what it outputs. It should output an array, and in that case follow the code that pallavi put in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can go with `get_the_category()`, but since you tagged your question with `Twig` and `Timber`, I thought maybe you want to do it «the Timber way».

With Timber you can access a lot of functionality via methods on the objects. For the TimberPost class, there’s a method [`terms()`](http://timber.github.io/timber/#terms), which will get you all terms for a post. Pass the name of the taxonomy you want to get terms for. In your case: `category`.

### single.php

```
<?php

$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = Timber::get_post();

$context['post'] = $post;

// Get all categories assigned to post
$categories = $post->terms( 'category' );

// Get only the first category from the array
$context['category'] = reset( $categories );

Timber::render( 'single.twig', $context );
```

In versions below Timber 1.x there were also methods like `category()` and `categories()` to get either one or all terms of the category taxonomy, but they seem to be **deprecated now**.

### single.twig

In your Twig file, you then can easily access the slug through

```
{{ category.slug }}
```

You can also directly call the `terms()` method from Twig and pass the result to a for loop. This will echo out all categories assigned to the post.

```
{% for category in post.terms('category') %}
    {{ category.slug }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great answer and glad to see someone pushing «the Timber way»

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to solve your issue:

```
foreach (get_the_category() as $category) {
    echo $category->slug .' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$context[ 'category' ] = Timber::get_term(['taxonomy'=>'category']);
```

and in your twig file:

```
{{ category.title }}
```